# Storing Data for a Home Page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, custom-list, office-365, data

I'm fairly new to Sharepoint so bear with me!  I have a project site and a request has been made to display (formatted) data on the home page relating to the project (ie title, scope, project members, costs etc).  I created a custom list, added columns for the data and now have that data stored.

The problem I have is how to display that data on the home page?  I can't figure out how to display the list item data in a nice way (ie not a list view as some fields wil be paragraphs of text and it will be the only item in the list), but now I wonder if I've gone about it in the wrong way and maybe there is a much easier way to do this?

The point is obviously to make the project details visible as soon as you hit the site, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed that list views are ugly...

.If the data is not used elsewhere why does it need to be in a list?

If it needs to be in a list then this will be difficult without some custom coding to retrieve the data and display it how you wish.

An alternative could be to use the publishing Infrastructure. Publishing pages have metadata which can hold the data you need, and you could create a page layout in sp designer that automatically shows this data on the page in a consistent way.

See this link for more info on doing this

[Customize a publishing page layout](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-designer-help/customize-a-publishing-page-layout-HA010174129.aspx)

Comment: I think that's kind of what I was trying to ask, does in need to be stored in a list.  If I can store the data in the page itself that would probably be way better, but how do I add/retrieve the metadata?

Comment: Yes you can create custom metadata fields for pages and these fields could hold the project info. The link above should show you how to surface metadata fields in a page layout. I would suggest having your home page be a different content type than basic pages as you don't need these fields on every page in your site.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2013, you have newly introduced Client Side Rendering / JSLink property in Web Parts which you can use to customize the look and feel of List View Web Part..

[image: JSLink Property]

Please have a look at below examples:

- [Client-side rendering (JS Link) code samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)
- [JS Link for SharePoint 2013 Web Parts–A Quick Functional Primer](http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2012/js-link-for-sharepoint-2013-web-partsa-quick-functional-primer/)
- [Using JSLink to change the UI of a SharePoint list/view](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/using-jslink-to-change-ui-of-sharepoint_20.html)
- [SharePoint 2013: Customize a field type by using client-side rendering](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Customize-0c9698e1)